# CSS to display elements side-by-side fails on iOS / Safari

Tags: html, css, safari

*I'm not really good at CSS. That ... plus the fact that I just spent almost an hour trying to achieve something that I could've done in a minute using a `<table>` ... but nowadays, styling your HTML with `tables` is considered bad. OK. So I'm plowing forward with CSS ...*

So any help would be appreciated.

I'm trying to display this:

[image]

So my html becomes this (there're multiple items in the list):

```
<ul class="utl">
 <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="#" class="utlimg"></a>
    <a href="#"><h2>HeaderTitleGoesHere</h2></a>
    <p>Small description text goes here.</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and CSS is:

```
* {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.utl{
    list-style: none outside none;
    padding: 1em 4px 4em 4px;
    margin: 10px 0px 30px 0px;
}
.utl li {
    padding: 2px 0;
    margin: 0.8em 0 1.8em 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
.utl h2{
    margin: 0 0 0.4em 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.utl p{
    margin: 0.4em 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.utlimg{
    float: left;
    margin: 0px 1em 1em 0px;
    max-width: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
}
```

This somewhat works when I try it in the dev console in Chrome (although the text seems to overflow under the image on the left):

[image]

But when I load it on my iPhone it looks totally wrong like this (in Safari):

[image]

So what am I missing there?

Comment: Can you apply the flex concept in your code?

Comment: I made changes please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code. Hope it will help you. If any changes please let me know.

```css
.utl li{
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.right-part{
  padding-left: 20px;
}
h2{
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<ul class="utl">
 <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x150/000/fff" class="utlimg"></a>
    <div class="right-part">
      <a href="#"><h2>HeaderTitleGoesHere</h2></a>
      <p>Small description text goes here.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not aware of it. What's the `flex` thing?

Comment: Flex concept is very useful for CSS. A flex container expands items to fill available free space or shrinks them to prevent overflow. Most importantly, the flexbox layout is direction-agnostic as opposed to the regular layouts (block which is vertically-based and inline which is horizontally-based)

Comment: Follow this link. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp

Comment: I'll have to look into it. Thanks.

Comment: @c00000fd Do you want to continue with your old code and make some changes?

Comment: IDK yet. I need to test it. And it also depends on the browser support for that `flex`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204773/discussion-between-revti-shah-and-c00000fd).